# How to display message right around autocompletion input when no items available

Tags: angular, angular-material

I'm trying to display a block if no items are present for autocompletion right below the input field. By default the autocomplete component is visible only if there are items.

Here is the code I use:

```js
<input [formControl]="control" [matAutocomplete]="auto" matInput type="text">

<mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete" 
                  (optionSelected)="onOptionSelected($event.option.value)"
                  [displayWith]="displayWith">
  <mat-option *ngFor="let item of items" [value]="item">
    <span class="label">{{ item.label }}</span>
  </mat-option>
</mat-autocomplete>
```

Thanks for your help!
Thierry

Comment: What do you mean by block? Do you want to display a message like `No items found` or you neeed to display a div just like autocomplete div but with something other than items?

Comment: Thanks very much for your comment! Yes, a `div` instead of the autocomplete div...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a `*ngif` with `items.length` such that div will be visible only when there are no items.

```js
<input [formControl]="control" [matAutocomplete]="auto" matInput type="text">
<div *ngIf="!items.length">
  <!--    your content here-->
</div>

<mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete"
                  (optionSelected)="onOptionSelected($event.option.value)"
                  [displayWith]="displayWith">
  <mat-option *ngFor="let item of items" [value]="item">
    <span class="label">{{ item.label }}</span>
  </mat-option>
</mat-autocomplete>
```

Comment: Thanks very much for your answer! Yes agreed but we need to add some styling to simulate the absolute position... I hoped there was something built-in from angular material

Comment: No, there is nothing built-in angular material for this as per my knowledge. Why do you need absolute position though? This div will be displayed just below this input. Right?

Answer (score 0):

Just add first disabled option "no items" with `*ngIf='!items.length'`.

```html
<mat-autocomplete>
  <mat-option *ngIf='!items.length' disabled>
    <span class="label">No items</span>
  </mat-option>
  <mat-option *ngFor="let item of items" [value]="item">
    <span class="label">{{ item.label }}</span>
  </mat-option>
</mat-autocomplete>
```

If you have any problems with implementations, below is working StackBlitz example:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-n9c5ey?file=app%2Fautocomplete-filter-example.html

Comment: Thanks very much for your answer! The problem with this is that the autocomplete area is only displayed when there is at least one item...

Comment: @thierry-templier i added StackBlitz example that shows working case.